# Karate framework "no-auth" authorization problem

Tags: karate

Is there any way in Karate through which I could use authorization as `no auth`?

I went through its documentation, but didn't find anything regarding the `no auth`.

I have a simple service request which is running fine in the Postman with authorization as `No Auth`, but here in Karate I am not able to figure out what to use so that it would consider the authorization as `No Auth`.

Please help!

Comment: Start with understanding the HTTP Basic Auth example: https://github.com/intuit/karate#http-basic-authentication-example - if that doesn't help, you can edit your question and paste the `cURL` export from postman - which will allow others to help you. karate is simple once you know what headers are needed, but if you can't make that clear - no one can help

Comment: @vdrulerz I dont think you have to give anything if you dont have any authorization. can you add your feature file so we can see? No auth does not need no auth to be mentioned